# Error on inserting new line on gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am trying to add a new row into a gridview but for some reason i'm having a problem in the for loop.

Directly goes to **dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)** and of course,  have an error *"'row' argument cannot be null.Parameter name: row"*, because the **dtcurrentTable.NewRow** was not executed.

Why is this happening?

```
 Private Sub AddNewRowToGrid()
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
    If Not IsNothing(ViewState("CurrentTable")) Then

        Dim dtCurrentTable As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)
        Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing

        If dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i as Integer = 1 To i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count
                ' Extraem-se os valores das Textbox
                Dim box1 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(0).FindControl("Artigo")
                Dim box2 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("Descricao")
                Dim box3 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("IVA")
                Dim box4 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(3).FindControl("PU")
                Dim box5 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(4).FindControl("Desconto")
                Dim box6 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(5).FindControl("UN")
                Dim box7 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(6).FindControl("Quantidade")
                Dim box8 As TextBox = Dados.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(7).FindControl("TotalLiquido")

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow

                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Artigo") = box1.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Descricao") = box2.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("IVA") = box3.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("PU") = box4.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Desconto") = box5.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("UN") = box6.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("Quantidade") = box7.Text
                dtCurrentTable.Rows(i - 1)("TotalLiquido") = box8.Text

                rowIndex += 1

            Next i
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)
            ViewState("CurrentTable") = dtCurrentTable

            Dados.DataSource = dtCurrentTable
            Dados.DataBind()

        End If

    Else
        Response.Write("ViewState null")
    End If
    SetPreviousData()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `For` loop is defined wrong, thats why you're getting an error:

`For i as Integer = 1 To i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count`
evaluates to
`For i as Integer = 1 To True`
(because i is always <= Rows.Count) 
which VB translates as
`For i as Integer = 1 To -1`
which means your loop never runs.

It
should be

`For i as Integer = 1 To dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count`

Also, there's something odd about the way you use `drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow`. Why is that inside the loop when you don't do anything with it in the loop? It gets executed multiple times and then `dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)` only gets called once.

Its hard for me to correct because I can't figure out what you're trying to do, but that bit looks dodgy to me.

Comment: It was that. :)
Modified the for loop and now i have all working correctly.

Thank you codeulike.